# How to extract a number within a range from a string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to look for and return a score between 0 and 10 in a string.
message examples

```
"Toni gets 9"
"8 for Sam"
"10 is a reasonable score for Jed"
```

This is what I've tried:

```
message.split.find do |score|
 (0..10).include? score.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do like this:

```
regexp = /\b(?:10|[0-9])\b/

'Toni gets 9'[regexp]
# => "9"

'8 for Sam'[regexp]
# => "8"

'10 is a reasonable score for Jed'[regexp]
# => "10"

'11 is my score'[regexp]
# => nil

'01 is your score'[regexp]
# => nil

'1000 is no score'[regexp]
# => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message.split.find { |string| (0..10).include?(string =~ /\A\d+\z/) }
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work, for example it'll match "11".  I'd like to delete it but you'd have to un-accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["8 out of gem", "ruby got 10", "ali receives 13 marks"]

a.each do |i|
  if ((i =~ /\d/) > -1 && (i =~ /\d/) < 11)
    puts i
  end

end
```

**Output:**

```
8 out of gem
ruby got 10
```

Comment: I'm trying to extract the score

Comment: Based on what spuggy showed they tried already, I think they want it to return "8" or "10", and not puts anything.  Also, you're solution will match things like "xyz8 out of gem" (it'll puts "xyz8").

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
message.split(' ')[1].scan(/\d/)
```

Or this:

```
message.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '')
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
message.each_char{ |c| if c.ord<11 or c.ord>0 }
```

Comment: This only looks at the second word in the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
messages = ["Toni gets 9",
"8 for Sam",
"10 is a reasonable score for Jed",]

irb> messages.collect{|msg| msg.split.find{|str| str.match /\b^(10|[0-9])\b/}}
 => ["9", "8", "10"]
```

Comment: @spuggy now it won't match 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
input = [ "0 Toni", "Toni gets 9", "8 for Sam", "10 is", "11 is" ]
input.each do |sentence|
  if(sentence =~ /\b([0-9]|10)\b/)
    puts sentence
  end
end
```

I have used word boundary(`\b`) around the regex so that it doesn't match any digits sticked with the text.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as `message[/\b([0-9]|10)\b/]`